# l1-regularization of network weights not going to zero

Tags: regularization, keras

I'm working on an autoencoder that transforms a very high dimensional space (~10,000 inputs) through two hidden layers of 256 nodes each.  (I settled on these values given the reconstruction error but I don't think the actual dimensions of the hidden layers are that important.)  In order to impose sparsity on the weights of the network, I've included l1-regularization on the input and the first hidden layer.  Here's the code describing the model.

```
activation = 'selu'
dims = (10000, 256, 256)
do_level = 0.5
reg_penalty = 10e-5

input_vec = keras.Input(shape = (dims[0], ))
hidden_enc = layers.Dense(dims[1], activation = activation,
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1(reg_penalty))(input_vec)
encoded = layers.Dense(dims[2], activation = activation,
                       kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1(reg_penalty))(hidden_enc)
encoded_do = layers.Dropout(do_level)(encoded)
hidden_dec = layers.Dense(dims[1], activation = activation)(encoded_do)
hidden_dec_do = layers.Dropout(do_level)(hidden_dec)
decoded = layers.Dense(dims[0], activation = activation)(hidden_dec_do)
autoencoder = keras.Model(input_vec, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

When I look at the actual weights going into the first or second hidden layer, there are a large proportion that are less than 10e-3, but none are actually set to zero.  Shouldn't l1-regularization drive these small weights to zero?

I'm working in Python 3.8 with Keras v2.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradient descent is unlikely to ever update such that it sets some weights to exactly 0. This is because at any given step, it's simply unlikely to estimate a gradient update for a parameter that is *exactly* enough to force the parameter to zero. Additionally, even if the update does force the value to exactly zero at some step, then this may be *undone* at a later update step. This is because unconstrained gradient descent does not respect the constraints on the loss function implied by the $L^1$ penalty.

Gradient descent is distinct from sparse learning methods like LASSO. These methods use specialized optimization algorithms solve a constrained optimization problem which allows them to pin coefficients to exactly 0 when that's the optimal thing to do. For instance, the LASSO optimization problem is a quadratic program, so using a QP solver is one way to get an exact solution.

Comment: Any references on implementing LASSO as a quadratic program for a neural network?

Comment: Thank you!  All of the tutorials I've read explicitly describe absolute zero weights.  Clearly they're not considering to optimization procedure.

Comment: @mhdadk It's not hard to find a treatment of LASSO, or an outline of how to solve it using quadratic programming, or software implementations of the same. But this isn't the problem that Keras is designed to solve, so it will involve some amount of programming effort to implement a QP solver inside of Keras. One reason it might be uncommon is that state-of-the-art neural networks typically have millions of parameters and very large data sets, making it impractical to solve the QP exactly.